# Find the highest unique digit

Tags: code-golf, number, integer

Surprisingly we haven't had a simple "find the highest digit" challenge yet, but I think that's a *little* too trivial.

Given input of a non-negative integer, return the highest **unique** (ie not repeated) digit found in the integer. If there are no unique digits, your program can do anything (undefined behaviour), other than the numbers that are non unique in the input of course.

The input can be taken as a single integer, a string, or a list of digits.

### Test cases

```
12         -> 2
0          -> 0
485902     -> 9
495902     -> 5
999999     -> Anything
999099     -> 0
1948710498 -> 7
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: Can we take input as a string instead?

Comment: Given the last test case, I think we are forced to take input as a string... (leading zeroes can't be represented in integers)

Comment: @Leo that was my bad actually, basically mashed the numbers on my keyboard, didn't notice the leading zero. But yes, input can be taken as a string

Comment: Then why can't we just take a list of digits (or numbers for that sake)?

Comment: Can we throw an error if there are no unique digits?

Comment: @Adám "undefined behaviour" generally means you can do anything, including summoning nameless horrors from the void if that saves bytes.

Comment: @MartinEnder in fact I'll happily knock off 50% of your bytes if your code successfully summons cthulhu upon there being no unique digits ;)

Comment: @Mayube Can we take a list of digits?

Comment: @Adám sure, most people are only splitting it into a list of some form anyway, I'll explicitly state accepted input formats on the post

Comment: Regarding the list of digits: can it be either a list of integers or a list of characters? (`[1,2,3]` vs `['1','2','3']`)

Comment: @Arnauld no. List of integer digits only.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 40 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [movatica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86751/movatica).

```python
lambda i:max(x*(i.count(x)<2)for x in i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHTKjexQqNCSyNTLzm/NK9Eo0LTxkgzLb9IoUIhM08hU/N/QVEmUDhNQ93Q0sTC3NDAxNJCXVNTQUHZnAsuZWJhamlgBBYGAWVLhJQBXBQiZYCQsrS0NLC0ROhClbJElgr1c3F18/RzdfkPAA)

#### 42 bytes

Works for both String and list of digits parameter types. Throws an error for no unique digits, kind of abuses of that spec:

```python
lambda i:max(x for x in i if i.count(x)<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHTKjexQqNCIS2/SKFCITNPIVMhM00hUy85vzSvRKNC08ZI839BUSaQnaahbmhpYmFuaGBiaaGuqamgoGzOBZcysTC1NDACC4OAsiVCygAuCpEyQEhZWloaWFoidKFKWSJLhfq5uLp5@rm6/AcA)

---

### Explanation

- `lambda i:` - Declares a lambda function with a string or list of digits parameter i.
- `max(...)` - Finds the maximum value of the generator.
- `x for x in i` - Iterates through the characters / digits of `i`.
- `if i.count(x)<2` - Checks if the digit is unique.

Comment: 40 bytes: `lambda i:max(x*(i.count(x)<2)for x in i)`

Answer (score 16):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Mr. Xcoder* notifying that a digit list is valid input.

```
¢ÏM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0KLD/b7//0eb6ChY6iiYgkkDHQWjWAA)

**Explanation**

```
¢     # count occurrences of each digit in input
 Ï    # keep only the digits whose occurrences are true (1)
  M   # push the highest
```

Comment: Wait so in 05AB1E, `2` is not truthy; only `1`? :o

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: Correct!

Comment: That seems both very useful and very bothersome... That is interesting :o :D

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: It often comes in handy, but it can be a disadvantage when the challenge says *return a truthy value*, when a lot of languages can return any positive integer or maybe even a non-empty string.

Comment: A strikethrough on the number for is _not_ easy to see!

Answer (score 8):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 15 bytes

```
/&.sDo
\i-.tN@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fTa/YJZ8rJlNXr8TPQf//f0NLEwtzQwMTSwsA)

#### Explanation

```
/...
\.../
```

This is a simple framework for linear code that operates entirely in Ordinal mode (meaning this program works completely through string processing). The unfolded linear code is then just:

```
i..DN&-sto@
```

What it does:

```
i    Read all input as a string.
..   Make two copies.
D    Deduplicate the characters in the top copy.
N    Get the multiset complement of this deduplicated string in the input.
     This gives us a string that only contains repeated digits (with one
     copy less than the original, but the number of them doesn't matter).
&-   Fold string subtraction over this string, which means that each of
     the repeated digits is removed from the input.
s    Sort the remaining digits.
t    Split off the last digit.
o    Print it.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Comment: -1, doesn't "_summoning nameless horrors from the void_" if there are no unique digits. ;) (Read: +1, great answer as always.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I tried, but it didn't save bytes. Maybe [Dark](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Dark) might be a more appropriate language...

Answer (score 7):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 16 bytes

```
O`.
(.)\1+

!`.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3z9Bj0tDTzPGUJuLSzFBT@X/f0MjLgMuEwtTSwMjLhNLMGVpaWlgacllaGliYW5oYGJpAQA)

#### Explanation

```
O`.
```

Sort the digits.

```
(.)\1+
```

Remove repeated digits.

```
!`.$
```

Fetch the last (maximal) digit.

Comment: Too bad Deduplicate doesn't help here :(

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>18</strike> 12 bytes

```
Ｆχ¿⁼№θＩι¹ＰＩι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NclLCoAgEADQq7icAQUFIaWltOwQEkgDkvnr@lObtu8dZ2xHiZk5lSbAaBSUBGx1xtwhlHkNqDLEPoAQpUEU@8yD7kbf/L4yG2/dYrT1jtXDqucX) (Link to verbose version)

Prints nothing if no solution is found. The trick is that the `for` loop prints every unique number in the input string, but without moving the cursor, thus the value keeps reprinting itself until the final solution is found.

The previous version printed the characters A to Z when no solution was found, hence the comments:

```
ＡααＦχＡ⎇⁼№θＩι¹Ｉιααα
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8jUUchUdOaKy2/SEHD0EBTASocklqUl1hUqeFaWJqYU6zhnF@aV6JRqOOcWFyikampqWOoqaMA5egkgpA1V0BRJlANkPX/v6GliYW5oYGJpcV/3bL/usU5AA) (Link to verbose version)

Comment: That's an interesting undefined behavior :)

Comment: This sounds Finnish to me :D

Comment: @fedorqui nice to see you here! Yeah, but Charcoal is easier to learn than Jelly or O5AB1E, and it's funnier to use in ASCII-art games. :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
→fo¬hgO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8dC2/4/aJqXlH1qTke7///9/QyMuAy4TC1NLAyMuE0swZWlpaWBpyWVoaWJhbmhgYmkBEgECAA) (Test suite, crashes on the last test case since it has no unique digits)

This is a composition of functions in point-free style (the arguments are not mentioned explicitely anywhere). Takes input and returns output as a string, which in Husk is equivalent to a list of characters.

#### Explanation

```
Test case: "1948710498"

      O    Sort:                             "0114478899"
     g     Group consecutive equal elements: ["0","11","44","7","88","99"]
 fo¬h      Keep only those with length 1*:   ["0","7"]
→          Take the last element:            "7"
```

*The check for length 1 is done by taking the head of the list (all elements except the last one) and negating it (empty lists are falsy, non-empty lists are truthy).

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>46</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

Takes input as a string. Returns RangeError if there are no unique digits.

```js
s=>f=(i=9)=>s.split(i).length-2?f(--i):i
```

-7 bytes thanks to Rick Hitchcock

-1 byte thanks to Shaggy

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>g=(i=9)=>s.split(i).length-2?g(--i):i


console.log(f("12")())         // 2
console.log(f("0")())          // 0
console.log(f("485902")())     // 9
console.log(f("495902")())     // 5
//console.log(f("999999")())   // RangeError
console.log(f("999099")())     // 0
console.log(f("1948710498")()) // 7
```

Comment: Remove the alert for 39 bytes:  `(s,i=9)=>s.split(i).length-2?f(s,--i):i`.  You can avoid the stack overflow for 42 bytes:  `(s,i=9)=>s.split(i).length-2?i&&f(s,--i):i`.

Comment: Save a byte with currying: `s=>g=(i=9)=>s.split(i).length-2?g(--i):i` and then call it with `f("12")()`

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 37 bytes

```
f s=maximum[x|x<-s,[x]==filter(==x)s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2DY3sSIztzQ3uqKmwka3WCe6ItbWNi0zpyS1SMPWtkKzOPZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoKSoaWJhbmhgYmlhdJ/AA)

How it works:

```
  [  |x<-s   ]          -- loop x through the input string s
    x                   -- and keep the x where
     [x]==filter(==x)s  -- all x extracted from s equal a singleton list [x]
maximum                 -- take the maximum of all the x
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 41 bytes

```r
function(x,y=table(x))max(names(y[y==1]))
```

An anonymous function that takes a list of digits, either as integers or single character strings. It precomputes `y` as an optional argument to avoid using curly braces for the function body. Returns the digit as a string. This takes a slightly different approach than [the other R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128874/67312) and ends up being the tiniest bit shorter! looks like my comment there was wrong after all...

`table` computes the occurrences of each element in the list, with `names(table(x))` being the unique values in `x` (as strings). Since digits are fortunately ordered the same lexicographically as numerically, we can still use `max`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqfStiQxKSdVo0JTMzexQiMvMTe1WKMyutLW1jBWU/N/mkayhomOqY4xGFoCobmOOVAcAA)

Comment: Nice! I didn't expect doing something with `table` would be shorter (plus I can never remember how to get `names` to work).

Comment: `<2` for another byte.  There should never be a zero in the counts.

Comment: `y=table(scan());max(names(y[y<2]))` is a few bytes shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 40 bytes

```
lambda i:max(x+9-9*i.count(x)for x in i)
```

Only works for lists of digits. The edge case '990' works fine :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc9NCsIwEAXgvacYyCbRqaSttR3Bk6iLqAQD9odSIZ4@piBttenMbvh4vGne3aOuUqePZ/dU5fWuwBxKZbndUERrs73Vr6rjVui6BQumAiNc0xp/0/wUY3IRAgLDIFkNTC6gnsmR7bDADAnlLJUBTRktsmxkhMPOWJTu/6EMwkm72IO@YY6xx32J4ssZ5L9p4X99mvsA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Looks like you've got everything down :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
►≠O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0XY86F/j///8/2kTHUscUiA10jGIB)

### Explanation

```
►≠O
  O order the elements
►   max by
 ≠  inequality(selects least frequent elements)
    then returns the last of the least frequent elements
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ọtᵒtᵍhth
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@Hu3pKHWycBcW9GScb//4aWJhbmhgYmlhb/owA)

#### Explanation

```
Example input: 495902

ọ          Occurences:    [[4,1],[9,2],[5,1],[0,1],[2,1]]
 tᵒ        Order by tail: [[0,1],[2,1],[4,1],[5,1],[9,2]]
   tᵍ      Group by tail: [[[0,1],[2,1],[4,1],[5,1]],[[9,2]]]
     h     Head:          [[0,1],[2,1],[4,1],[5,1]]
      t    Tail:          [5,1]
       h   Head:          5
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Thanks to Leo for suggesting a slightly neater solution at the same byte count.*

```
▲‡ȯf=1`#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0TY8aFp5Yn2ZrmKD8//9/JUNLEwtzQwMTSwslAA)

#### Explanation

```
  ȯ       Compose the following thre functions into one binary function.
      `#  Count the occurrences of the right argument in the left.
    =1    Check equality with 1. This gives 1 (truthy) for values that 
          appear uniquely in the right-hand argument.
   f      Select the elements from the right argument, where the function
          in the left argument is truthy.
          Due to the composition and partial function application this
          means that the first argument of the resulting function actually
          curries `# and the second argument is passed as the second
          argument to f. So what we end up with is a function which selects
          the elements from the right argument that appear uniquely in
          the left argument.
 ‡        We call this function by giving it the input for both arguments.
          So we end up selecting unique digits from the input.
▲         Find the maximum.
```

Comment: `¬←` could be more simply `=1`, same bytecount though :)

Comment: @Leo Ah yeah, I was too lazy to test whether the currying would work without parentheses. I need to trust more in the type inference. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 chars = 19 bytes

Method: multiply elements that occur multiple times by zero, and then fine the highest element.

```apl
⌈/×∘(1=≢)⌸
```

`⌸` for each unique element and its indices in the argument:

`×` multiply the unique element

`∘(`…`)` with:

`1=` the Boolean for whether one is equal to

`≢` the tally of indices (how many times the unique element occurs)

`⌈/` the max of that

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@NR24RHPR36h6c/6pihYWj7qHOR5qOeHUCJQys0DBWMNBU0dAyAhImChYKpgqWCAVjIBMhC8CwV4BDOM4DyDIE0SK@5giFQDKTPQhMA)

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
⌈/×∘(1=≢)⎕U2338
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/41HbhEc9HfqHpz/qmKFhaPuoc5Hmo76poUbGxhZA2UMrNAwVjDQVNHQMgISJgoWCqYKlggFYyATIQvAsFeAQzjOA8gyBNEivuYIhUAykz0ITAA)

Identical to the above, but uses `⎕U2338` instead of `⌸`.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
(t=9;While[DigitCount[#][[t]]!=1,t--];t)&
```

thanks @Martin Ender

here is Martin's approach on my answer

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
9//.d_/;DigitCount[#][[d]]!=1:>d-1&
```

Answer (score 4):

### R, <s>45</s> 43 bytes

`function(x)max(setdiff(x,x[duplicated(x)]))`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jQjM3sUKjOLUkJTMtTaNCpyK6PCMzOUMjpbQgJzM5sSQ1BahEM1ZTkytNI1nDRMdUxxgMLYHQXMdcU/P/fwA)

Takes input as a vector of integers. Finds the duplicated elements, removes them, and takes the maximum. (Returns `-Inf` with a warning if there is no unique maximum.)

Edited into an anonymous function per comment

Comment: `max(x[!duplicated(x)])` is quite a bit shorter, but this is a great answer. I knew the way I was going to do it was not this good. Also you can remove the `f=` from the beginning, as anonymous functions are perfectly valid answers.

Also, you can use TIO to test your functions if you use this format: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjM3sUKjOLUkJTMtTaNCpyK6PCMzOUMjpbQgJzM5sSQ1BahEM1ZT83@aRrKGiY6pjjEYWgKhuY45UBwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks! I think the 'duplicated' function doesn't count the first occurrence of a duplicate element so your version wouldn't quite work

Comment: ah, good point. I almost never use `duplicated` but I actually thought up another, shorter answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda l:max(1/l.count(n)*n for n in l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCoMwEITP@hRzTEqwiViqgk9iPdgfMRDXIJG2T59KAraFWZj5hh37duNMuR@aizf9dL33MPXUv5g6muw2r@QY8QNhmBcQNMFw/xy1eUDVaWIaTXZ1jKeJXTQ5DGzrWyWQd2krtysESoGTQCUgIy5C@ENVCF/9IrkjFVxcPAuo0MW1cv@Q3Qc)

Comment: I enjoyed this, it’s great!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->x{(?0..?9).select{|r|x.count(r)==1}[-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iWsPeQE/P3lJTrzg1JzW5pLqmqKZCLzm/NK9Eo0jT1tawNlrXMLb2f4FCWrS6oaWJhbmhgYmlhXosF1jExMLU0sAIxjOAMSwtLQ0sLZF4liDefwA)

Comment: Ruby ties Python :)

Comment: Because 42 is always the answer. :-)

Comment: @GB Or is it: `->x{x.chars.select{|r|x.count(r)<2}.max}`

Comment: That would be 2 bytes shorter and ruin the whole thing. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>27</strike> <strike>97</strike> <strike>86</strike> <strike>58</strike> <strike>57</strike> 75 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;

n=>n.GroupBy(i=>i).Where(i=>i.Count()<2).Max(i=>i.Key)-48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv/Yo9JqBBpWCltgcFPaggevAc4qoL7UaTVCzit9dWEbzNDDOPMb5vrMOm8sRn2Nc@YJlG/06tiW9pZArtPWydPTtdPiMAH3QgA3dLR9hoYiG7FGBRsZn64FpCjzjkcIKs4SxntXS2us5qQVlOUh0u6PCj1dxWHIScjqTa6Mc3W2Et@3HSdMj0A55b9rZAdXAUUJzEz@9QH9uPKKSUXfMVvZrhJE7Gw0E8SdrhGw)

Thanks @CarlosAlejo

Comment: This does not work with "1948710498" as input (returns "9" instead of "7"), and you must add `using System.Linq;` to the byte count.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Oops! Sorry! Just now read the specifications fully. Will edit the solution soon.

Comment: Edited. Are there any optimisations I can make?

Comment: Sure: try using `OrderBy(...).Last()` instead of `.OrderByDescending(...).First()`, for instance. Or even better, change your last part with `.Max(i=>i.Key)` after the `Where` clause.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Thanks! Edited.

Comment: And even better: you can get rid of the `Select` clause and apply the transformation (changing `'0'`with its ASCII value `48`) only to the final result, so you get: `n=>n.GroupBy(i=>i).Where(i=>i.Count()<2).Max(i=>i.Key)-48`.[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv/Yo9JqBBpIKltgcLetCC6MFziKsu2I0mqVjEb6@tIjinmWF4jPFDYx22tSc@wa7xAas0@k9qTXxLI3PR3sPG2ZPT1TMC8EEHMnC3dIBSEwvZtwCLms3MB9cRBsQhhyNkLWc5q6Wz9XXeCMpykmp/RocfrwpbcxByNpaq1I9vt8JGDuNp2yPTD7iw7O0F1d5RQHEUv7xFfeg@opBS9stX9GrjZJKMxvDTGw "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: You need to include `using System.Linq;` into the byte count here.

Comment: Wrote this off the top of my head so haven't checked it but I believe this will be shorter if it works: `using System.Linq;n=>n.Where(c=>n.Distinct(h=>h).Contains(c)).Max()-48` or maybe this: `using System.Linq;n=>n.Where(c=>n.Distinct(h=>h).Any(a=>a==c)).Max()-48`

Comment: You can use the C# Interactive compiler now without counting `using System.Linq;`, and you can also move the both the Where and the GroupBy things into the Max call for 38 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrpOZV2KnkKZg@z/P1i5PzzexQiMTxHDOL80r0Ui0tUu0tc3UtDGyz7Qy0NQ1sfhvzRUA1FeikaahZGhpYmFuaGBiaaGkqWn9HwA "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, <s>30</s> 28 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)

```bash
fold -1|sort|uniq -u|tail -1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifVpqXXJKZn6eQm1gRX5qXWahQrZCanJGvoGKoUPM/vSi1QEE3X0Gvpji/qKQGLK9bWlOSmJmjoGv4v5aLC67N0AjBNkAwTSxMLQ2QpEwsUfmWYIDCN0DmG1qaWJgbGphYWvyHaAUA)

---

#### [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 20 bytes

```bash
sort|uniq -u|tail -1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifVpqXXJKZn6eQm1gRX5qXWahQrZCanJGvoGKoUPM/LT8nRUHXsKY4v6ikBiyrW1pTkpiZAxT8X8vFBddkaIRgGyCYJhamlgZIUiaWqHxLMEDhGyDzDS1NLMwNDUwsLf5DtAIA)

If input is given as a list of digits, one per line, we can skip the fold stage. That feels like cheating though.

Comment: Replace `grep -o .` with `fold -1` to save 2 bytes.  I agree that an input integer given as a list of digits is stretching the rules too far.

Comment: +1 just because it is bash

Answer (score 3):

## [<>< (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 93 bytes

```
0l1-l2-$:?v~~o;         
v&]{[-3lr <   |.!01~$r&\
>r$1-:?!v$rl3-[{]:&:&=?^
@&::&:$~/|.!01 $}&~$?(
```

[Try it in my interpreter](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMGwxLWwyLSQ6P3Z+fm87XG52Jl17Wy0zbHIgPCAgIHwuITAxfiRyJlxcXG4+ciQxLTo/IXYkcmwzLVt7XTomOiY9P15cbkAmOjomOiR+L3wuITAxICR9Jn4kPyhcbiAgICAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IiIsInN0YWNrIjoiMTQ0MjIiLCJtb2RlIjoiY2hhcnMifQ==)

[Found a fun bug in my interpreter testing this](https://github.com/mousetail/Fish/commit/aef7487c6fe7c54eee4659f9e04be968abd1c781)

Expects input pre-pushed to the stack

### Explanation

[image]

Top row: Setup. Push 0, the current maximum, l-1, the total number of iterations of the outer loop, and l-2, the total number of iterations in the inner loop. Initially both are the same.

Second row left: Shift left 1, then move the top item to the register. This is the candidate largest member.

Third row: Compare the register for each digit. If none match go down. Otherwise go up to second row right.

Second row right: Reset, then try another digit. This happens if the digit is equal to another.

Last row: We have found a unique digit! Now we check if it's better than the current max value, if so replace it. Then reset and jump to the start.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

-2 thanks toTwiNight.

```apl
⌈/⊢×1=(+/∘.=⍨)
```

`⌈/` the largest of

`⊢` the arguments

`×` multiplied by

`1=(`…`)` the Boolean for each where one equals

`+/` the row sums of

`∘.=⍨` their equality table

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@NR24TqRz0d@o96twLxCkNbbf1HHTP0bIFsoFAtUMWhFRqGCkaaChoGQGyiYKFgqmCpYAAWMQGyEDxLBUswG0gCeYZAGqTaXMEQKAZSaaHJlQFTBYaaAA)

Comment: Since `0` is never the highest unique digit except for `0` itself, you can save 1 byte using `×` instead of `/⍨`, then save another byte converting that into a train

Comment: @TwiNight Nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 4 bytes

I/O as a digit array.

```
ü l1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=/CBsMQ&input=WzEsOSw0LDgsNywxLDAsNCw5LDhd)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

Takes input as a list of digits. Returns `0` if there are no unique digits.

```js
s=>s.reduce((m,c)=>m>c|s.filter(x=>x==c)[1]?m:c,0)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.reduce((m,c)=>m>c|s.filter(x=>x==c)[1]?m:c,0)

console.log(f([1,2]))                 // 2
console.log(f([0]))                   // 0
console.log(f([4,8,5,9,0,2]))         // 9
console.log(f([4,9,5,9,0,2]))         // 5
console.log(f([9,9,9,9,9,9]))         // (0)
console.log(f([9,9,9,0,9,9]))         // 0
console.log(f([1,9,4,8,7,1,0,4,9,8])) // 7
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 40 bytes

```php
<?=array_flip(count_chars($argn))[1]-48;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUnmerZGhpYmFuaGBiaaFkzWVvB5S1TSwqSqyMT8vJLNBIzi/NK4lPzkgsKtYAa9DUjDaM1TWxsP7/HwA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 42 bytes

```php
<?=chr(array_flip(count_chars($argn))[1]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUnmerZGhpYmFuaGBiaaFkzWVvB5S1Tc4o0kgsKkqsjE/LySzQSM4vzSuJT85ILCrWAGvS1Iw2jNW0/v8fAA)

Comment: -2 bytes: `<?=array_flip(count_chars($argn))[1]-48;`

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>89</s> <s>85</s> 79 bytes

```java
a->{int i=10,x[]=new int[i];for(int d:a)x[d]++;for(;i-->0&&x[i]!=1;);return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY8/b4MwEMX3fIrrEoFiLKhSNakLUpdKHTqlG/Lg8ic6SmyETUqE@OzURrR7kQfr7t3v3rtKXEWgmkJW@dfUdJ81ZpDVQmt4Fyhh2AAsXW2Esd9VYQ4Xq3kn06I8pxxEe9b@PApQ2X20M1jTspOZQSXph3qT5nWpnlGalCdQQjyJIBlsCRhHIelTHsviG5yOnJWq9ZyWPwm/T3O@280thkGQhNttb2fu4oj5rC1M10pANk7On80pTjdtigtVnaGNDWlq6ZVUNE19e9E2jPdrxIeI3I@@/18qXMHsyYE8kCMJVznuLbmePpK/t5oOV9KR5dztjySyO9wdh2XLuBmnHw)

-6 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen's insight!

Comment: You can replace `return i>0?i:0;` with `return i;`. The output will be -1 for test case `[9,9,9,9,9,9]`, but that is fine with the challenge: "_If there are no unique digits, your program can do anything (undefined behavior)._".

Comment: Indeed, I can since the current revision. Before I couldn't because of the test case `0`. It's something I oversaw in the previous golf! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 67 bytes

```java
s->{int i=9;for(s=" "+s+" ";s.split(i+"").length!=2;i--);return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xboNADIb3PIV7E4hygYiqWFcyVurQKWPV4UqAml4OxJlIUcSz06uKsobFsvx/@v21@qzj9vgz9@OXoRJKo52Dd00WrhsAx5r9tfWUHJmMrEdbMnVWvi7Ly4EHss0jvFmummrYQw0FzC7eX8kyUIGq7obAFQJE5CI/lZOuN8QBRUKE0lS24e@HYqcojkM1VDwOFkhNs9p4g8VrETl3dISTtwv@3358gg7/RAEOF8fVSXYjy95HbGxQS9335hKIdCfCUN3FklVUlj9hsq4ww9UoIiaIq9AUs/w5TTLMb/h2e6cbb93TZpp/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```
0{\:~-.}./.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DapjrOp09Wr19PXq/msqcKUmZ@QrqJuqK9gqpCkoWSkYGhmbmBoZQ8UtkMQtLYEyFnApc4SUpYmFuaGBiaUFzDgDuJylpaWBpaXCfwA)

Comment: This is really nice, and since "The input can be taken as a single integer, a string, or a list of digits." you can actually do `0{\:~-.}./.~` for 12: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DapjrOp09Wr19PXq/msqcKUmZ@QrqJuqK9gqpCkoWSkYGhmbmBoZQ8UtkMQtLYEyFnApc4SUpYmFuaGBiaUFzDgDuJylpaWBpaXCfwA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

**APL ([NARS2000](http://www.nars2000.org/)) 16 chars, 23(?) bytes**

```
{↑⌽⍸1=+⌿⍵∘.=⍳10}
```

(input as array of digits, e.g. {↑⌽⍸1=+⌿⍵∘.=⍳10}4 9 5 9 0 2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 113 bytes

```
U(l)=max([min([\left\{l[n]=l[i]:-1,l[n]\right\} for i=join([0...n-1],[n+1...l.length+1])]) for n=[1...l.length]])
```

Takes input as a list.

[Try it out and see versions that make slightly more sense](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xy4naheu1w)

Answer (score 2):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 134 bytes

```python
N
Count i while _%81/48 {
_+(1-_/3^(_%81-44)%3/2)*3^(_%81-44)-_%81+N
}
Count i while _ {
Count j while _/3^(13-i)%2 {
Write 57-i
0
}
}
```

Outputs a non-digit character if there are no unique digits. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXtXCUN/EQqGaK15bw1A3Xt84TgMkpmtioqlqrG@kqYUkoAtiaPtx1aIbAtQOEcmCiYDMMTTWzdRUNQJKhhdllqQqmJrrZnIZAHXX/v9vaGliYW5oYGJpAQA)

#### Explanation

We partition the accumulator into two sections: `_%81` stores the most recently read character, while `_/81` stores ten counters, one for each digit, denoting whether that digit has occurred 0, 1, or 2+ times. For example, an accumulator value of 3214945 (20001100002001 in base 3) represents the following:

```
Occurrences of       Next character
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
-------------------  --------------
2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  7 (character code 55, or 2001 in base 3)
```

When a digit occurs more than 2 times, we cap its occurrence count at 2. Then once all digits have been processed, the answer is the highest digit that has 1 as its occurrence count.

```python
### Part 1: read the input and count digit occurrences ###

# Read the first character into the accumulator
N
# Loop while the most-recently-read character was a digit (>= charcode 48):
Count i while _%81/48 {
  # The digit we just read is _%81-48
  # Its occurrence count is _/81/3^(_%81-48)%3
  # We add 1 to the occurrence count; but if the occurrence count was already 2,
  # we also subtract 1, leaving it unchanged
  _+(1-_/81/3^(_%81-48)%3/2)*81*3^(_%81-48)
  # Clear out the previously read character and read a new character
  _-_%81+N
}

### Part 2: output the highest unique digit ###

# Count up i, starting at 0, until the accumulator gets zeroed out
Count i while _ {
  # 9-i is the current digit
  # Its occurrence count is _/81/3^(9-i)%3
  # Loop if the occurrence count is odd (i.e. 1, not 0 or 2):
  Count j while _/81/3^(9-i)%3%2 {
    # Output that digit
    Write (9-i)+48
    # Zero out the accumulator, causing both loops to end
    0
  }
}
```

If there are no unique digits, the `i` loop keeps going past `9`; some part of the newline character stored in `_%81` triggers the `j` loop, and a non-digit character is written out. (The golfed and ungolfed versions output different characters, and I haven't taken the trouble to analyze why, but it's guaranteed not to be a digit because `9-i` is less than 0 at this point.)

Answer (score 1):

## [F#](http://fsharp.org/), 88 bytes

```fs
let f i=Seq.countBy(fun a->a)i|>Seq.maxBy(fun a->if snd a>1 then 0 else int(fst a))|>fst
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclBCsIwEEbhq/wEhGRRaaBguzALr@AJQp3BQDtRMwWF3j3GlbvH97h0a5Zc60IKRjpf6Xmc8yZ6@VjeBLEL0aU9/HyN778mtkVuiC546J0EPWgphCRquWgbbg8t6uPViAXmMBtYhvHTMJ58P0yjcfUL)

An improved approach from my first effort, results in less bytes.

*Points of interest: `fst` and `snd` return the first and second elements of a tuple respectively.*

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
Max@Position[RotateRight@DigitCount@#,1]-1&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ṢŒrṪỊ$ÐfṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4bmixZJy4bmq4buKJMOQZuG5gP///zE5NDg3MTA0OTg)

Comment: [well](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128801/48934)

Comment: @LeakyNun outgolfed, son

Comment: @Mayube but the core algorithm is the same

Comment: @LeakyNun no, it's quite different.

Comment: @LeakyNun I decided to post separately...basically a big difference is that in my case I just decide which to keep, while steenbergh takes some heads or something...

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

1 byte thanks to isaacg.

1 byte thanks to FryAmTheEggman.

```
e{I#.g
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e%7BI%23.g&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%2212%22%0A%220%22%0A%22485902%22%0A%22495902%22%0A%22999999%22%0A%22999099%22%0A%221948710498%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
eS.m/Q
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eS.m%2FQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%2212%22%0A%220%22%0A%22485902%22%0A%22495902%22%0A%22999999%22%0A%22999099%22%0A%221948710498%22&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
eS.m/Q
eS.m/QbQ    Implicit variable introduction
  .m   Q    Find all minimal elements of the input by the following function:
    /Qb     Number of appearances in the input
eS          Take the maximum element remaining.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 59 bytes

```perl
for$x(split//,<>){$d[$x]++};for($x=11;--$d[--$x];){}print$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0ilQqO4ICezRF9fx8ZOs1olJVqlIlZbu9YaKKehUmFraGitqwsUBRIVsdaa1bUFRZl5JSoV//8bWppYmBsamFhaAAA)

Comment: Shortened to 40 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAvc/qukRKvEx2prp@UXObhZq8TbOqRYG5ZnZOak6uoC5YBEfOz//4aWJhbmhgYmlhYA "Perl 5 – Try It Online"). (you can look up `-F` flag on [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) if needed)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 31 bytes

```matlab
@(a)find(hist(a,0:9)==1)(end)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRMy0zL0UjI7O4RCNRx8DKUtPW1lBTIzUvRVPX8H9iXrFGtKGCgoIlEJsAsQUQmwMxSMwAKgaSs4jV/A8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 41 bytes

```
lambda s:max(s,key=lambda o:s.count(o)<2)
```

Accepts input as string or list of strings

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth -- 8 bytes

```
eSf!t/QT
```

And also

```
eS-Q.-Q{
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eSf%21t%2FQT&input=%2212233%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%2212%22%0A%220%22%0A%22485902%22%0A%22495902%22%0A%22999999%22%0A%22999099%22%0A%221948710498%22&debug=0) and [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eS-Q.-Q%7B&input=%2212233%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B4%2C8%2C5%2C9%2C0%2C2%5D%0A%5B4%2C9%2C5%2C9%2C0%2C2%5D%0A%5B9%2C9%2C9%2C9%2C9%2C9%5D%0A%5B9%2C9%2C9%2C0%2C9%2C9%5D%0A%5B1%2C9%2C4%2C8%2C7%2C1%2C0%2C4%2C9%2C8%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
eSf!t/QT  # Takes string
  f       # Filter characters T of implicit input
     /QT  # by counting occurrences of that character in the input
   !t     # keeping only characters that occur once (i.e., !(# occurrences - 1)
 S        # Sort (puts them in ascending order
e         # Take the last (highest)
```

And

```
eS-Q.-Q{  # Takes list of digits
       {  # Deduplicate the list
    .-Q   # Take the original list, and remove each element in the deduplicated list once (so only duplicated digits are left)
  -Q      # Remove these duplicated digits from the list
eS        # As before, sort and take the last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>33</s>  25 bytes

```perl6
{max keys .comb∖.comb.repeated}
```

input is either an Int or Str.

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TU9LboMwEN37FKOIFiwCGEQSECJql123y24oMS0qHwubChQl656gl@muR@lFqM2nyWxm3rx582YYbYrt0HIKH1s7jRAqe7hN6wOFeDiWSQfvtOdgp3X58vv5NWa7oYwmgh5Ogxy@E5QLiKHIK8oN/PNtc1bkwnCeuQm6tddBFo7qP4omQsrpSSoixIqkAnOURyirm3mTtQdDyyvWijVotGM0lU4YjghAummzm/lPgeOA9VBl0TzQUN4WakQ9MW/Cisz5Qq6nNTKNrJ2VwtBvXMJ1DGfQ1Qm6LC4WZzBW8qpJjVedrKc74tEaY3QaXA@WkHoPEbjGBPnBJiTegkPkh9d4g8IxFnxf9eItr15Vm1zaBLmhH@xc4oeBwrs/)

```perl6
{max keys $_∖.repeated}
```

input is a list of digits.

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TU5NToNAFN7PKV4aFCYUGAhtIYRGl651aWKQDkrkL8xgIE279gRewiO461F6EZzhx/Zt5n1vvr@K1tm6bxiFz7UZBwjlHdzG5Y5C2O/zqIUP2jFQXs5f32ZNKxpxujv0gnTHKeMQQpYWlGn49GuyKku5Zj0zHVRjq4JYLHl/5HWAZMKTUASoyqIC9EEeoKSsJydjC5qSFlXDl6DQtqKxSMKwRwAiTZnS9P8vsCwwHookmAg1ZU0mKbK8pp9@RjMzLvNXLEkpm0nL0U48IyXJuabe2ISpGI6gyiqqWC5RR9AWot2oxotW7GOfcKiAMTr0tgPzCL2DCFxjglxv5RNnxj5y/Wu8Qv4wM74vOv6eFm/yTC5ngmzf9TY2cX1P4s0f)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  max                  # the maximum from
    keys               # the keys (digits) out of the following Set

        $_             # the Input list of digits
      ∖                # Set minus (not ｢\｣)
        .repeated      # the repeated digits (implicit method call on ｢$_｣)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
⌈/{⍺×2-≢⍵}⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEc9HfrVj3p3HZ5upPuoc9Gj3q21j3p2cD3qmwqUTANSlDP//9cwVDDS5NIwfNS7xQBImyhYKJgqWCoYgEVNgCwEz1IBDuE8AyjPEEiD9JorGALFQPosNAE)

Comment: [`⌈/×∘(2-≢)⌸`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEc9HfqHpz/qmKFhpPuoc5Hmo54d/x/1TQXKpAEpLoqZ/zUMFYw0uTQMH/VuMQDSJgoWCqYKlgoGYFETIAvBs1SAQzjPAMozBNIgveYKhkAxkD4LTQA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 70 bytes

Input is taken as a List of digits, as per question parameters.

```
n->n.stream().reduce(0,(p,q)->p>q||n.indexOf(q)!=n.lastIndexOf(q)?p:q)
```

The power of Streams in the palm of your hand!

The secret here is the beautiful `reduce` function. Starting with a 0, we walk through our list of digits and perform a retaining algorithm, keeping the one we've got (`?p:q`) if it's bigger than the new one (`p>q`) or if the new one isn't unique (`n.indexOf(q)!=n.lastIndexOf(q)`)

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `||` to `|`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 42 bytes

Same byte count as the other Ruby answer, but different approach.

```
->x{x.chars.group_by{|d|x.count d}[1].max}
```

Crashes when there are no unique digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukIvOSOxqFgvvSi/tCA@qbK6JqUGKJZfmleikFIbbRirl5tYUfu/QCEtWt3Q0sTC3NDAxNJCPZYLLGJiYWppYATjGcAYlpaWBpaWSDxLEE8BCJQVkosSizNSi/8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Machine Code (32-bit, requires built-in FPU), 35 bytes

```
C8 10 00 00 D9 EE DD 14 24 DD 5C 24 08 8B 01 FE 04 04
83 C1 04 4A 75 F5 6A 0A 58 48 FE 0C 04 75 FA C9 C3
```

The above code defines a function in 32-bit x86 machine code that finds the unique highest digit in an array of integer values. (The question says we can take the input as a "list of digits", and assembly language is [like C in that it lacks a built-in list/array type, but rather represents them as a pointer and length](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/list-input-in-c-and-length-argument). Therefore, the function is prototyped in C as follows:

```
int __fastcall FindHighestUniqueDigit(const int * ptrDigits, int count);
```

As the prototype suggests, this function is written to follow [Microsoft's fastcall calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall), which passes arguments in registers. The first parameter (`ptrDigits`) is passed in `ECX`, and the second argument (`count`) is passed in `EDX`. The return value is, as always, returned in `EAX`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZF9T4MwEMb/51NcMCZAOlM22CBTE2XzS4ghWGA0YWCgzCbLvrp4rPiy6baEo9fe7x6uD2y0YqzrWFU2Alge1yC9aVAl6fML3IEeysALpU1DSYdY@KFcLnFd4LkTyrGjcjdQOUXee8TVDuUTctRR4U1Qy1a58xDKmYt1jCnmFMPFPscbegLF7RmsBfjNYKLPNa0RseAM1Li8FGBYOO@TLE3j@8wi/duEKIqFqPlrK9IoMowsbgSLi8I08WLDJVFRu@IlK9okhdtGJLy6ye81rVdex7w0@iSuV4zsvbGsfrMxta0Gv2aoSuXWFmwgMIbd/KAs3quhTP@U8nooOQQ8Ai4BnwD9RySr2h/SP0vyzUD65PA5Jhsuj0l6gky/NO09oKadkX5LyTCSp7reauzIDP06CUudgPo9BnqEs5rmaQJtQr2zRF4TmJ4j0KVLBN9cINCVS0SKGjbtEWTqVLR1CXSu7brug2VFvGq60Xoy/gQ)**

Here are the ungolfed assembly mnemonics:

```
FindHighestUniqueDigit:
   enter  16, 0                  ; reserve 16 bytes of space on the stack for a table
   fldz                          ; load 0 in the first x87 FPU register (st0)
   fst    QWORD PTR [esp+0]      ; store value in st0 on the stack, at offset 0
   fstp   QWORD PTR [esp+8]      ; store value in st0 on the stack, at offset 0, and pop st0
ReadDigits:
   mov    eax, DWORD PTR [ecx]   ; read next digit from array
   add    ecx, 4                 ; increment pointer to reference next digit (ints are 4-bytes long)
   inc    BYTE PTR [esp + eax]   ; increment value in table for this digit
   dec    edx                    ; decrement counter (length of array)
   jne    ReadDigits             ; keep looping as long as there are more digits to read
   push   10
   pop    eax                    ; space-efficient way to put '10' in EAX so we start with highest digit
ProcessDigits:
   dec    eax                    ; decrement EAX
   dec    BYTE PTR [esp + eax]   ; decrement value in table for this digit
   jnz    ProcessDigits          ; if that table value is now zero, we found a match; otherwise, keep looping
   leave                         ; undo effects of ENTER instruction
   ret                           ; return, with result in EAX (digit ID)
```

I suppose the code requires a bit of explanation…

Basically, what we do is create a table in memory, with enough space to store a unique count for each of the 9 possible digits (0 through 9).

```
| esp+0 | esp+1 | esp+2 | esp+3 | esp+4 | esp+5 | esp+6 | esp+7 | esp+8 | esp+9 | unused |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|--------|
|   9   |   8   |   7   |   6   |   5   |   4   |   3   |   2   |   1   |   0   |   ??   |
```

The first `ENTER` instruction is responsible for allocating this space on the stack. We allocate 16 bytes because it's good practice to keep this a power of 2 for alignment purposes, 8 bytes isn't enough, and it doesn't hurt or cost anymore code bytes to allocate more than we need. The next three instructions are responsible for *zeroing* out all entries in this array. It's basically equivalent to `memset` in C, but shorter. We could have used the x86's `REP STOSD` string instruction, but that requires some setup (getting the right values in the right registers), and it turned out that (ab)using the x87 FPU to do 8-byte stores was shorter (required fewer bytes of code). All we do is load 0 at the top of the x87 FPU stack, which is pseudo-register `st0`. Then, we store that value across the first 8 bytes of the table, and finally, we store that value across the next 8 bytes of the table, popping it off of the x87 FPU stack at the same time.

The next section of the code is `ReadDigits`. This just iterates through the array of digits that we were passed, one digit at a time, and increments the unique counter for that digit in our table. You should be able to figure out exactly how this works by reading the comments for each of the instructions.

Finally, we come to the final phase, `ProcessDigits`. Actually, the `PUSH`+`POP` instructions right above this label are conceptually part of this phase, too. They just initialize `EAX` with 10 so that we'll start processing the table values for the *highest* possible digit, 9. Inside of the `ProcessDigits` loop, we eagerly decrement `EAX`, and then decrement the value in the table for the corresponding digit. If the resulting table value/counter is 0, then we've found our match, and we exit the loop. Otherwise, we keep looping and trying smaller digits. (Note that we could have done a comparison here—e.g., `cmp  BYTE PTR [esp + eax], 1`+`jnz`—and in fact that's what we're *logically* doing, but the decrement was shorter to encode.)

Notice that if we never find a matching digit, then the code exhibits undefined behavior: it just keeps looping through memory, decrementing values and waiting until one is non-zero. When it finally finds one, it will terminate and return the ID, but the ID will be meaningless, and more importantly, it will have stomped all over the stack, decrementing values aimlessly!

The very last two instructions just clean up the stack (`LEAVE`) and return, with the return value (the highest unique digit that we found) left in `EAX`.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
9A,sqfe=W%X#-
```

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=9A%2Csqfe%3DW%25X%23-&input=1948710498)

```
9    e# Push 9 to stack
A,s  e# Push "0123456789" to stack
q    e# Push input to stack ("1948710498")
fe=  e# Create array containing number of occurences of each digit in input number ([1,2,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,2])
W%   e# Reverse that array ([2,2,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,1])
X#   e# Get index of 1 in that array (2)
-    e# Calculate 9 - returned index to get highest unique digit (7)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 38 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Max(x=>n.Count(a=>a==x)<2?x:0)-48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZBC8IgGIDhu79i3fygDRUjbdMOQRAURJfOsrmS4gs2R/57a3svz9uOZTuGfJywbcY4BHysA0Zb9IXJaCxWF5domufwmTBSZ6wzJkEj9mnHoJQq199neHt6wurq/YvCypQcyH0I0Z8DetrTm3fdsgBQZy4II1JtNBNE6gW9NMP@cC3VljOp1Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```julia
s->maximum(c for c=s if count(==(c),s)<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcjBDkAgGADgu6f451QbW1mmNplXISJTbdJ4@7hx/L4t7magd9JynBfjUig7O9zGRosUaH@AkgGMBuWjO5GUSOEi4LbCaXZT1ofVX6BRTgXjDSVM8Bx/y3gtSPUf@io9)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>43</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
Max@*Cases[{d_,1}->d]@*Tally
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Yb8983scJByzmxOLU4ujolXsewVtcuJdZBKyQxJ6fyf0BRZl6Jg1aagr6DQnW1oY6CUa2OQrUBiDDRUbDQUTDVUbDUUTCASpiAeahilmAeAqGIGSDEDMFMiKnmOgqGYEmIgRa1tf8B)

Comment: Removed 14 bytes by skipping `IntegerDigits`: according to the comments, the function can be given a list of digits instead of a number.

Comment: Removed 1 byte by using the operator form of `Cases`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
▲fȯ¬←LgO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@jaZvSTqw/tOZR2wSfdP////9HRxvqGMXqRBsAsYmOhY6pjqWOAVjEBMhC8Cx14BDOM4DyDIE0SK@5jiFQDKTPIjYWAA)

Input is list of digits.

```
▲fȯ¬←LgO
▲           # maximum value of
 f          # filter list to retain only truthy values
      gO    # list: sort digits and group equal values together
  ȯ         # filter condition: combine functions:
    ←L      # length minus one (so length 1 = FALSE)
   ¬        # NOT (so length 1 = TRUE)
```

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbhEfTdp3bmu7/////aEMdSx0THQsdcx1DHQMgy1LHIhYA "Husk – Try It Online") I think

Comment: [3 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0XY86F/j///8/2kTHUscUiA10jGIB "Husk – Try It Online") but this one's very different

Comment: @Razetime - That's much, much, better than mine!  Post it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
'?$Oṅ;G
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJB4bmgIiwiIiwiJz8kT+G5hTtHIiwiIiwiMTJcbjBcbjQ4NTkwMlxuNDk1OTAyXG45OTk5OTlcbjk5OTA5OVxuMTk0ODcxMDQ5OCJd)

Takes input as a string.

#### Explained

```
'?$Oṅ;G
'    ;  # From the input, keep only items where:
 ?$O    #   The count of the item in the input
    ṅ   #   Is <= 1
      G # Get the biggest digit from the remaining items.
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwixIondOG5hTtzdGgiLCIiLCIxMlxuMFxuNDg1OTAyXG40OTU5MDJcbjk5OTk5OVxuOTk5MDk5XG4xOTQ4NzEwNDk4Il0=) for 8

Comment: @lyxal Erm if you want, you're welcome to edit my answer to add in the explanation! :3

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJB4bmgIiwiIiwiJz8kT+G5hTtHIiwiIiwiMTJcbjBcbjQ4NTkwMlxuNDk1OTAyXG45OTk5OTlcbjk5OTA5OVxuMTk0ODcxMDQ5OCJd) for 7

Comment: [Try it Online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJB4bmgRyIsIiIsIic/JE/huYU7IiwiIiwiMTJcbjBcbjQ4NTkwMlxuNDk1OTAyXG45OTk5OTlcbjk5OTA5OVxuMTk0ODcxMDQ5OCJd) for 6 using `G` flag.

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 That can be 5 removing the trailing `;`.

Comment: @Steffan good catch

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>43</s> 32 bytes

```arturo
$=>[tally&|select[k,v]->v=1|max]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?p2cHUR)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 100 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBBT8MgFAfwO5/iZSc4jLVNzUbjDho9Gg@6kzELrhRRSiu8Jm2WffZKZzTa@G6P/48/CeEgrRxN3TYeIUwL79BY/ugHQpqXN3VA2Dnz0akbow3eyR6OBKBUFdTSOCq9DgVceS@Hpwf0xulnVkw3ELZwHCdX0b74itg21tKea9907fVATakcGhwYr4xF5eme7zNuldP4epkx/q6GwGvZxnMZzu@zuPaMa4X3/tYGRZcpGyFOG/vROlrRRSryzTpNcrFZMAawWsGazEi@uRBJdo6niUTMSfKTfpNkToQQiRC/W/4j4i9ZpkB3Lv6Lcapk0Z/IiYyf)

```scala
def f(x:String)=Try(x.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.length<2).keys.map(_.asDigit).max).getOrElse(-1)
```

Ungolfed vesrion. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBBT8MgGAbge3/Fl53gMNY2NSuNM9Ho0XjQnYxZcKWIUlrhq1lj9tsr7aLRRm4v3wMvwe@FEcOg67ZxCH5MrENt2IPro6h5fpV7hK3V75281krjrTjAZwRQygpqoS0RTvkCLp0T/eM9Om3VEy3GEwibSQJ8CANVSETbtsMCTozC5gJCy2mXKdd07VVIpbSosaes0galIzu2S5mRVuELnENK2ZvsPatFGybCT4@iIR4oUxLv3I3xkiwTGk3VbWhCY0lFFgnP8nUSZzxfUAqwWsF6TrL8jMfpNB5XIHxO4p/pN4nnhHMec/77lv8I/0uWCZCtDb@qrSxp8MfoGA3DFw)

```scala
import scala.util.Try

object UniqueDigitMax {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f = (input: String) => Try(input.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.length < 2).keys.map(_.asDigit).max).getOrElse(-1)

    println(f("1948710498"))  // 7
    println(f("485902"))      // 9
    println(f("0"))           // 0
    println(f("999099"))      // 0
    println(f("999999"))      // -1 (Undefined)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, <s>106</s> 74 bytes

```kotlin
{n:List<Int>->n.groupingBy{it}.eachCount().filterValues{it==1}.keys.max()}
```

It's a real shame [we never got `toDigits()`](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/todigits-function-for-int/15298).

Takes input as a list of digits, errors if there are no unique digits.

[Try it Online!](https://pl.kotl.in/qvWI1-V5Y)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 49 bytes

> The input can be taken as a single integer, a string, or a list of digits.

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsIwEAXv/Yqlp@QSDBRsAyv4AZ7Ek4isMSmRNJUkglL67THiO84wL2nyVObbw@gMB3IBlnI3FixL6pijCyPHJKzz2USmcZeEnl8hsyui5oiSi4neBeDXTDVnFMekYB8jfc7/gwtXcAouA8LSQN2z0uwDs6yVQ9dv5aYb@pbzKtdmLV8)

```scala
def f(s:String)=s.filter(c=>s.count(_==c)==1).max
```

Ungolfed version.

```scala
object Main {
  def f(s: String): Char = {
    s.filter(c => s.count(_ == c) == 1).max
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f("1948710498"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 77 bytes

Not the best Java Stream solution, but a different approach.
Input is a String (because for obscure reasons `sum` and `max` aren't easily accessible in Streams of Lists of non-primitive integers).
Outputs `-48` in the "Anything" case.

```java
s->s.chars().filter(e->s.chars().filter(c->c==e).sum()==e).max().orElse(0)-48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxbsIwFEV3vuLJky1IFFAQSVHo1K2dGKsOxnFoqBMi20FUFWO3fkL7c/xIahwHmoIly9Y9fu9d3w3dUW@TvjVVvRI5AyaoUvBE8xI@BgOAvNRcZpRxeKTFKqVGBbAyZHipZV6uQZG5EQ@n50pTbbq4t6I9kkZ5C@WzVyoVJn6WC9MT8xsa8xYsSTjxVV1gYm8F3Ru@lQ9CcRwQL4ya@WmS8@sG7rZ5CnxHBT45q6ikxcia5PuKM81T8se45KoWGhLnz88wQkNbYz8CsHxXmhf@ttZ@ZX6oRYlx1yhJ2vJ7dPz@RHfo@POFyBABGrb6JYsbDguTq0vt@QWoXKvOl/UO4wl0a2T2BJyhlgbQo0GfhtE0DiZnGv@jcY9O@zS2y1ET8RUNzvRq7jgOo9k4COPI0hl0CRyaXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
cḅị
```

Input as a digit list.

##### Explanation

```python
cḅị  # Implicit input
c    # Counts of each
 ḅ   # Equals one?
  ị  # Filter input by above
     # G flag gets maximum
     # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 52 bytes

```
#(last(sort(for[c % :when(=((frequencies %)c)1)]c)))
```

Input is a string, returns a `char`, or `nil` if all digits are repeated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 16 bytes

```
╗1╤rR⌠$╜c⌡M1@í9-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8n/2oZ8H/R1OnGz6auqQoCMhReTR1TvKjnoW@hg6H11rq/gcx/ysZGilxKRkAsYmFqaUBiGNiCWVYggGEYQBmGFqaWJgbGphYWigBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 76 bytes

```c
d[58],i;main(){while((i=getchar())>0)++d[i];for(i=58;--d[--i];);putchar(i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8l2tQiVifTOjcxM09Ds7o8IzMnVUMj0zY9tSQ5I7FIQ1PTzkBTWzslOjPWOi2/CChjamGtq5sSrasLFNG0LiiFqMvUtK79/9/Q0sTC3NDAxNICAA)

Comment: Suggest `d[58];main(i)` instead of `d[58],i;main()`. Also, suggest `(~(i=getchar()))` instead of `((i=getchar())>0)`

Answer (score 0):

## **PHP**, <strike>79</strike> 76 bytes

[Try it online!](https://3v4l.org/ItuGv)

```
foreach(array_count_values(str_split($n))as$x=>$i){$h=($i==1&&$x>$h)?$x:$h;}
```

Use with `$n = 495902;` it will print `5`.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell v3+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 58 bytes

```
$i|% ToCharA*|sort|group|? count -lt 2|select -l 1 -exp N*
```

Assumes `$i` contains a string of digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqlgq6BuaGliYW5oYGJpoQ4UqVFVCMl3zkgsctSqKc4vKqlJL8ovLaixV0jOL80rUdDNKVEwqilOzUlNBnEUDBV0UysKFPy0/v8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 67 bytes

```
let f s=Seq.countBy id s|>Seq.filter(snd>>(=)1)|>Seq.maxBy fst|>fst
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZdDBCoJAEAbgu0/xsxAqqKxh6BxcqHO3jtEhygVB13JXUPDdbc2woDkMw8fMMIzUYd2oZpqqwkBC56fiGd2aTpnDgPIOPYpZZFmZovW0ugvh5X7sL1xfe9smtRmFTe8dptBGI3dg4wwWbxk@EcDdus5SM77y7Hz1JNsRX2as09fp13erExEnYn97YkqyNOYJZcx66uLiLJeNAsdSm0g27bWq4MlOwesDDD5CYT/QI59r2/ZoS2WkAtvs2fQC)

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, 53 Bytes

```
val f={a:String->a.filter{a.count{b->it==b}<2}.max()}
```

Declares a lambda, `f` that takes in a string; same algorithm as [the python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128787/60146). `it` is the implicit iterator of `a.filter`, and `b` is the explicitly declared iterator of `a.count` (because we can't use `it` again).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNCoMwEIX3nmKWyUJRSakRFXqGnmAsjYTGWGIsLSFnn0Z9m4/3w3st3mhL9EEDqg/Y3r3TdsoHLJQ2/ukCFo9lsz6M@aB934@xq2Mx45fxSGqzMKO2DN20tnBzDn/d@TBwCBkkqcUBS@UZg7awjzm8k/XGMsVWzrNIVNVUkmgusqxJyAPy0I4yoZKiuValkM0f)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 11 bytes

```
MX:_Na=1FIa
```

Takes input as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fN8Iq3i/R1tDNM/H///8mlqaWBkYA)

#### Explanation

```
          a  1st cmdline arg
        FI   Filter digits by this function:
   _Na        Count of digit in a
      =1      equals 1 (i.e. keep only digits that appear exactly once)
MX:          Max of resulting list (using : to lower precedence)
             Autoprint (implicit)
```

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 15 bytes

```
r$e`{0=1=},e~W=
```

Explanation:

```
r    e# Read token:          "2515"
$    e# Sort:                "1255"
e`   e# Run-length encode:   [[1 '1] [1 '2] [2 '5]]
{    e# Filter where:
 0=  e#   The first element: [1 1 2]
 1=  e#   Equals one:        [1 1 0]
},   e# End filter:          [[1 '1] [1 '2]]
e~   e# Run-length decode:   "12"
W=   e# Last digit:          '2
```

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 47 characters

(43 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
[./""|group_by(.)[]|select(length<2)[]]|max
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -Rr '[./""|group_by(.)[]|select(length<2)[]]|max' <<< 1948710498
7

bash-4.4$ jq -Rr '[./""|group_by(.)[]|select(length<2)[]]|max' <<< 999999
null
```

[Try on jq‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/D0qx0lcf3A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 15 bytes

```
k&gG{!L1-?$_|}X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/Wy3dvVrRx1DXXiW@pjbi////hkBoBITG/02A0BQIzf6bg7EFEFoCAA)

Takes input as a list of digits

### Explanation

```
k&gG{!L1-?$_|}X  Implicit input from commandline args
k                Sort in descending numerical order
 &g              Combine into single integer
   G             Split into digit runs
    {........}   Foreach loop..
     !L1-?       ..If length of item is greater than 1..
          $_     ....Remove item
            |    ..Endif
              X  Select highest value
                 Implicit output
```

To help visualize it a little, here's a run through showing the stack with input `122355567679`

```
k&gG{!L1-?$_|}X  [1,2,2,3,5,5,5,6,7,6,7,9]
k                [9,7,7,6,6,5,5,5,3,2,2,1]
 &g              [977665553221]
   G             [9,77,66,555,3,22,1]
    {!L1-?$_|}   [9,3,1]
              X  [9]
```

Answer (score 0):

## k, 12 bytes

```
|/@&:1=#:'=:
```

Example:

```
k)F:|/@&:1=#:'=:
k)F "1948710498"
"7"
k)F "99999"
"\000"
k)F "mississippi"
"m"
```

The translation to [`q`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/card/) as explanation

```
max where 1 = count each group@
```

Interpreter available [here](https://kx.com/download/)

Comment: I think this can be simplified to `|/&1=#:'=:` (provided it's run as `k4` code).

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
[:>./(".*1=#)/.~@":
```

Explanation:

```
": converts the number to a string
@ propagates the result (composes the verbs)
/.~ classifies items of the list into partitions of identical items
". * 1=# - fork of 3 verbs:
   1=# - 1 if the key is unique, else 0
   ". converts the keys back to digits
   * multiplies the key values by 1 or 0 depending on their uniqueness
>./ finds the max digit
[: caps the fork, since we have 2 verbs only for the key operator
```

Example:

```
   a=.123456547
     ": a
    123456547  NB. string
    </.~@": a
    ┌─┬─┬─┬──┬──┬─┬─┐
    │1│2│3│44│55│6│7│          NB. keys
    └─┴─┴─┴──┴──┴─┴─┘

(1=#)/.~@": a
1 1 1 0 0 1 1                  NB. mask for unique digits

(".*1=#)/.~@": a
1 2 3 0 0 6 7                  NB. digits multiplied by the mask, rendering
                                   duplicates to 0

([:>./(".*1=#)/.~@":) a        NB. finds the max nonrepeating digit
7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WL9rKTk9fQ0lPy9BWWVNfr85Byep/anJGvkKagqGRsYmpkTEXnGtpCRSwQIiYmpr@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 36 bytes

```perl
$_=join'',sort@F;s/(.)\1+//g;$_=chop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYrPzNPXV2nOL@oxMHNulhfQ08zxlBbXz/dGiiZnJFf8P@/iZGxocm//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYG/3UL3AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
|!|M
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C%21%7CM&i=[1+2]%0A[0]%0A[4+8+5+9+0+2]%0A[4+9+5+9+0+2]%0A[9+9+9+0+9+9]%0A[1+9+4+8+7+1+0+4+9+8]&a=1&m=2)

This program takes an array of digits.  It works by calculating the maximum "anti-mode".  I'm not sure if anti-mode is a real thing outside of stax, but it refers to the rarest element in list.

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 48 bytes

```
[1+dd;a+r:az0<A]dsAx[d]sD1[dd;a=D1+dB>M]dsMxr1-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9PC4MwDMXv/RSBHXYQoXW6afYHHF69iLfiIdgexjoQ66Dsy7s6N7fDEgjJL/B4T7WjgAxiSGEHArjfMkhHKQKl9hT0SA9@yBtlcydVYwshJ34s/P98Kj0vXS/CblyB0cPawo2uGggGbQew98ugmeTqUwIpQtogxUgJ0hZph5QiZUg5UuvVKsekyZ0ws6ypXGNrJsOlmq5lAiIwtWP8NSfriTfN33QK8Htn8G1/wwL4DNif/BMfnw)

Takes input as digits entered on the stack. I'm assuming this is a fair stand-in for a list of digits, since the justification for that was that folks were just dropping in boilerplate to turn an integer into a list of digits, and the task would be the same here (just... as a stack). Returns '10' on an entry w/ no unique digits.

Macro `A` builds an array `a` by taking each digit, loading the value in its own index (this will be 0 if thus far unassigned), adding itself, and storing this new value. We actually have to add 1 to every digit first so that 0 works correctly, and at the end we subtract 1 from our final result to make up for this. Ignoring that briefly for illustrative purposes, any index (let's call it *n*) of `a` will now have one of the following: 0 if *n* didn't exist as a digit in our original number, *n* itself if *n* was unique, or some multiple of *n* other than *n**1 if *n* existed and was not unique.

In `dc`, conditionals either run a macro if true or do nothing if false, so you *need* a macro for them to do anything. `[d]sD` is a macro, `D` that simply duplicates a value.

A 1 goes on the stack to act as a counter of sorts, and then macro `M` runs. `M` really just takes this counter number, loads that index from `a`, compares it to itself, and duplicates itself (by running `D`) if they're equal. So, if they aren't equal (digit didn't exist or wasn't unique), we're simply left with one instance of our counter; if they *are* equal, we now have another copy of it on the stack. Increment, and keep on going 1-10. When this is done, we swap the top two values on the stack and subtract one as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ċⱮ`Ị×⁸Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96ON6xIe7u46PP1R446HOxv@uxxuf9S05v9/QyMdBQMdBRMLU0sDINPEEkJbWloaWFrqKBhamliYGxqYWFoAAA)

Input as a list of digits

### How it works

```
ċⱮ`Ị×⁸Ṁ - Main link. Takes the list D on the left
  `     - Using D as both arguments:
 Ɱ      -   For each element in D:
ċ       -     Count occurrences in D
   Ị    - Insignificant; Yield 1 if abs(x) ≤ 1 else 0
     ⁸  - Yield D
    ×   - Multiply the digits by the insignificants
      Ṁ - Take the maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 27 bytes

```
[ non-repeating ?supremum ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc1DocGefu5WCsWpJcV6qRUlRYnFQHZhaWpecioSCyZVUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVVzaUABNUKhgpGCrVQtgGcZaJgoWCqYAkUMUISs8QQs0SCqGIGKGKGQDbITHMgywBskgVQrnZpaUmarsXuaIW8_DzdotSC1MSSzLx0BfviUqBrc0tzFWIhKlblJhYoFJckJmfrQQQWLIDQAA)

- `non-repeating` Get only the elements of a sequence that don't repeat.
- `?supremum` Get the largest element of a sequence, or return `f` for the empty sequence.