# lastIndexOf in CJam

Tags: tips, cjam

For the question [Find the highest unique digit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128784/find-the-highest-unique-digit) , here is [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132539/46313) :

```
9A,sqfe=W%X#-
```

At the end I am essentially trying to achieve a lastIndexOf. I do that by reversing my array, using indexOf, and subtracting from 9. This adds 4 (`9` `W` `%` `-`) extra bytes to get from indexOf to lastIndexOf.

Furthermore, if I didn't know my array was length 10 the code would be even longer, and secondly, this code returns `10` when indexOf is `-1` which may not be acceptable in many situations.

Any suggestions on a shorter way to do the lastIndexOf operation (generally or just as needed for this challenge)?

Comment: I want to ask the same thing, but in [tag:pyth] :P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks, I changed it to shorter. And I'm interested in solutions for any of the cases: 1) my challenge 2) variable array length 3) -1 case.

Comment: @geokavel OK, posting mine as an answer for 3) then. :)

Answer (score 2):

Splitting is sometimes a good way to do this. E.g.

```
e# Stack: ... haystack needle
a/);S*,
```

With variants, such as removing the `a` if both needle and haystack are strings.

Comment: Golfed: `a/)a*,`.

Comment: Note: doesn't handle `-1` case. Outputs `0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## 9 bytes

```
_,(@@W%#-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fqqwQUFqioJGTmpdekqGgq2CoqZBYrJCWWVRcopCZV5Kanlqkx8VVWPc/XkfDwSFcVVn3f2pKrPV/Q4VoMwVTBUMgNFIwBpImCgYKhrEA)

You must have `...element list` exactly like this in the stack. If `W` doesn't contain `-1` you must replace it with something that does evaluate to `-1`.

Comment: Note: doesn't handle `-1` case. Outputs length of array instead.

Comment: @geokavel Yeah the -1 case is being worked on...

Comment: In the case where the array has a known length, outputting the length could sometimes be usable, since at least it is a unique value that could not be confused with a valid index.