# Generalised Taxicab Numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, integer

\$\newcommand{T}[1]{\text{Ta}(#1)} \newcommand{Ta}[3]{\text{Ta}_{#2}^{#3}(#1)} \T n\$ is a function which returns the smallest positive integer which can be expressed as the sum of 2 positive integer cubes in \$n\$ different ways. For example, \$\T 1 = 2 = 1^3 + 1^3\$ and \$\T 2 = 1729 = 1^3 + 12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3\$ (the Hardy-Ramanujan number).

Let's generalise this by defining a related function: \$\Ta n x i\$ which returns the smallest positive integer which can be expressed as the sum of \$x\$ \$i\$th powers of positive integers in \$n\$ different ways. In this case, \$\T n = \Ta n 2 3\$ (note: this is the same function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number), \$\Ta n x i = \text{Taxicab}(i, x, n)\$)

Your task is to take 3 positive integers \$n, x\$ and \$i\$ and return \$\Ta n x i\$. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

In case \$x = 1 \$ and \$ n > 1\$, your program can do anything short of [summoning Cthulhu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128784/find-the-highest-unique-digit/214724#comment317467_128784), and for other cases where \$\Ta n x i\$ is not known to exist (e.g. \$\Ta n 2 5\$), the same applies.

### Test cases

```
n, x, i -> out
1, 1, 2 -> 1
1, 2, 3 -> 2
2, 2, 2 -> 50
2, 2, 3 -> 1729
3, 3, 2 -> 54
3, 3, 3 -> 5104
2, 6, 6 -> 570947
2, 4, 4 -> 259
6, 4, 4 -> 3847554
2, 5, 2 -> 20
2, 7, 3 -> 131
2, 5, 7 -> 1229250016
5, 8, 4 -> 4228
```

---

#### Properties of \$\Ta n x i\$

- \$\forall i : \Ta 1 x i = x\$ as \$x = \underbrace{1^i + \cdots + 1^i}_{x \text{ times}}\$
- \$\Ta n 1 i\$ does not exist for all \$n > 1\$
- \$\Ta n 2 5\$ is not known to exist for any \$n \ge 2\$

This is a table of results \$\{\Ta n x i \:|\: 1 \le n,x,i \le 3 \}\$, ignoring \$\Ta 2 1 i\$ and \$\Ta 3 1 i\$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
n & x & i & \Ta n x i \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 &  1 \\
1 & 1 & 3 &  1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 &  2 \\
1 & 2 & 2 &  2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 &  2 \\
1 & 3 & 1 &  3 \\
1 & 3 & 2 &  3 \\
1 & 3 & 3 &  3 \\
2 & 2 & 1 &  4 \\
2 & 2 & 2 &  50 \\
2 & 2 & 3 &  1729 \\
2 & 3 & 1 &  5 \\
2 & 3 & 2 &  27 \\
2 & 3 & 3 &  251 \\
3 & 2 & 1 &  6 \\
3 & 2 & 2 &  325 \\
3 & 2 & 3 &  87539319 \\
3 & 3 & 1 &  6 \\
3 & 3 & 2 &  54 \\
3 & 3 & 3 &  5104 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20576/66833). Imaginary brownies for beating my 14 byte Jelly answer

Comment: I was wondering why you used \$i\$ and \$x\$... but now I realise it spells "taxi" ha

Comment: @pxeger [Thank Adám for that](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56568959#56568959) :P

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
∞.ΔL¹m²ã€{ÙOy¢Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8vXNTfA7tzD206fDiR01rqg/P9K88tCjw/38jLiAEAA)

This is really slow, inserting `¹zmï` after `.Δ` limits the search space significantly: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9vc2FiaWX//@KIni7OlMK5em3Dr0zCuW3CssOj4oKse8OZT3nColH//zMKMgoy)

**Commented:**

```python
                # Inputs ¹=i, ²=x, ³=n
∞.Δ             # find the first natural number k that satisfies:
   L            #   each of the range [1..k]
    ¹m          #   raised to the i-th power
      ²ã        #   take the list to the x-th cartesian power
        €{      #   sort each x-tuple
          Ù     #   deduplicate the tuples
           O    #   sum each x-tuple
            y¢  #   count the number of k's
              Q #   is this equal to the last input?
```

`ã€{Ù` does the same as Python's [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), but there doesn't seem to be a builtin for this in *05AB1E*.

Comment: I replaced the second \$n\$ with \$k\$ as it's clearer that way.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + gtools, 84 bytes

```r
function(n,x,i){while(sum(rowSums(gtools::combinations(+T,x,re=1)^i)==T)<n)T=T+1;+T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZIxa8MwEIV3/4qDLBJ2oJLtmqR1904dqrmgGDUVWBJIMkkp/e2uXepYcmoCN33veHd6Ott7fpYNP9T9e6cbL41GOjtnEn@dPmQrkOsUsub02imHjt6Y1u33jVEHqfnY7FDKhnYraoLfJK5rhh81ZjVLyUPKvid3RDIYimLYwPYJSBJwmkH@x@mFD7Cc@@ldKNBZKGchH2wCoUiSDbTcHoUFL5yHhjvhwEsltqbzYDSw55exKXCu5lVITmKtGGpap9zFWvAEUtHd6OqMEqCMFSC4@wxWSJI4E/JfJmtZkWDQIkNylSGJoqI3Mye/CU4@@YLTFZ5fcRrtU9z@OhoNLhf88oAq/Otgwv3iBtZ4cBv9Dw)

Counts `T` up from 1, calculating the number of combinations of `x` numbers ≤`T` whose `i`th powers sum to `T`.
Stops at the first number that gives (at least) `n` combinations.

```r
function(n,x,i){    
                    # variable T (TRUE) initialized by default to 1
 while( ... )T=T+1  # while the condition (see below) is met, keep incrementing T
                    # 
 a=gtools::combinations(+T,x,re=1)  # all combinations of x numbers from 1..T (as rows of matrix)
 b=a^i              # raised to the i-th power
 c=rowSums(b)       # the row sums are the sums of each combination
 d=sum(c==T)        # when the row sums equal T, we have a combination of x i-th powers that equals T
 d<n                # the condition: we didn't get n combinations yet
                    #
 +T                 # finally, the condition fails, so we've got n combinations: return this value of T
}
```

---

For a base-[R](https://www.r-project.org/) solution (without the gtools library), swap `gtools::combinations(+T,x,re=1)` for `unique(t(apply(expand.grid(rep(list(1:T),x)),1,sort)))` (+23 bytes).

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 79 bytes

```
(n=1;While[Length@Select[PowersRepresentations[n++,#2,#3],#~FreeQ~0&]!=#];n-1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277XyPP1tA6PCMzJzXaJzUvvSTDITg1JzW5JDogvzy1qDgotaAotTg1rwSoIT@vODpPW1tH2UhH2ThWR7nOrSg1NbDOQC1W0VY51jpP11BT7X9AUWZeiYJDerSRjrmOcez//wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œċ³*⁴§ċ⁼⁵µ1#
```

A full program which (given enough time!) prints the result if it exists. Inputs are \$x\$, \$i\$, \$n\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//xZPEi8KzKuKBtMKnxIvigbzigbXCtTEj////M/8y/zM)** (Too slow for most of the test cases.)

#### How?

Brute-force (and an inefficient one at that):

```
œċ³*⁴§ċ⁼⁵µ1# - Main Link: x
         µ1# - Count up starting with k=x until 1 truthy result, then yield k, using:
  ³          -   1st program argument, x
œċ           -   all combinations (of x elements from [1..k]), allowing repeats
    ⁴        -   2nd program argument, i
   *         -   exponentiate (vectorises)
     §       -   sums
      ċ      -   count occurrences (of k)
        ⁵    -   3rd program argument, n
       ⁼     -   equal?
```

Note `œċ` does not give unordered repeats, for example `2œċ3` yields:
`[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]`

Comment: Nice! I had [this](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//xZPEi8KzKuKBtMKnxIvigbzigbUKMcOHMSP///8z/zL/Mw) for my 14 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 89 bytes

```javascript
(n,x,i)=>(F=q=>(g=(k,p,j)=>j?p**i>k?0:g(k-p**i,p,j-1)+g(k,p+1,j):!k)(++q,1,x)-n?F(q):q)``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dCoMgGIbPdxXuTNNWWtEPVGddR9FKytBaY3T3zbYoqOBD0Od7Xl7b4lOM5avp36ZUz2qu4xlKMpEGxQnM4kGfPIaC9KTVL23aG0aTiNSOOBTmclmISRHmyxKmei26CwQxHgglEzJlmsEBRQPK87lUclRd9egUhzWkBOhhCAHLAvR2gowA5w/ZAbIfXE3PvqSrSn0WHrij4W67l3S1PWq753RXz1rMC8/Y28LZRTV/r@YcP63NYMt2GQvmLw)

#### Commented

We recursively look for the smallest \$q\$ such that there exists exactly \$n\$ sums of the form:

$${p_1}^i+{p_2}^i+\ldots+{p_x}^i=q,\:p_{k+1}\ge p_k \ge 1$$

```javascript
(n, x, i) => (        // input variables, as described in the challenge
  F = q =>            // F is a recursive function taking a candidate solution q
  ( g = (             //   g is a recursive function taking:
      k,              //     k = current sum
      p,              //     p = number to be raised to the power of i
      j               //     j = remaining number of terms in the sum
    ) =>              //   
    j ?               //     if there's at least one more term to compute:
      p ** i > k ?    //       if p ** i is greater than k:
        0             //         abort
      :               //       else:
        g(            //         do a 1st recursive call with:
          k - p ** i, //           k = k - p ** i
          p,          //           p unchanged
          j - 1       //           one less term to compute
        ) +           //
        g(            //         do a 2nd recursive call with:
          k,          //           k unchanged
          p + 1,      //           p incremented
          j           //           j unchanged
        )             //
    :                 //     else:
      !k              //       increment the final result if k = 0
  )(++q, 1, x)        //   initial call to g with k = ++q, p = 1 and j = x
  - n ?               //   if the result is not equal to n:
    F(q)              //     try again
  :                   //   else:
    q                 //     success: return q
)``                   // initial call to F with q zero'ish
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/), <s>110</s> 108 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcvBCoJAGATge09hCKK4ga5JhGx4KRA6dDA6LBts9ps/2Ebu6tFXN0moCOb0zcxdmgru0mAhh5INLrIgOVVYA9@Dupkq3aG6ZkobqQrg6PuM5Q13O3ZU@GyBiz6Xlxp6m3pnOxKOswett89W1mnakY4cHhoNdpApAzdoNLHFnNkiQc8ZDg0qw0seEmsMFdZiY4Vi9sOUWNGb6Zfpm6d1HPz7NA9XdP1topE/j@W/T484DJZieAE)

```
(i=0;While[Length@FindInstance[i++==Tr[(v=Unique[]~Table~#2)^#3]&&LessEqual@@v,v,PositiveIntegers,#]!=#];i)&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 125 bytes

```scala
(n,x,i)=>1 to 1<<30 find(c=>Seq.fill(x)(1 to c map(Math.pow(_,i))takeWhile(_<=c)).flatten.combinations(x).count(_.sum==c)==n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBTsMwDL3vKyzEIZGq0qbruqFlEuLEAXEAiQNCU5amLNClZfFgEuLbh5tSYEiWKz@/Zzt2vVa1OjSrZ6MR7tTearUCs0fjSg8XbQsfI4A3VQP2uXNgVw4jGBwHuYCbFm3jHih8BHlgLtpHlstFCthAOp9nCVTWlUzLxa15jStb12zPWUhr2KiWXStcx23zzpYk5KhezP3a1oYt51JzHle1Qpoo1s1mZZ3qmnmqQPHOIVvGfreRRJTS8cP3tMbjpfLGgwTqyegRACyNgEyQ59EPQmFGfkBEQMjy5BgiUlqI2QBmvYx442OILE@TATw76@STYHmRzMbFn6rjYCKf/ZInA5pNx0X@W7tr1E/2d6yiHytLj7rlIZEKMRN5kqSTQUD4tC8vxJQTxkfkflYVV83WKL1m2N30I2i6XSqNO/rI4RdgGC9pb@RF8BkPVOW92SIb2LT3ZmM6Lr0B/EnXBjT1gVOEStF1ywie7Bud6LTXnPR12q11WDv2T@J3WhtTmjLQPvno8/AF)

**Approach**: for each candidate integer `c`, generate a list of `x` copies of `i`-powered integers lower than `c`, and count whether `n` (distinct!) combinations of length `x` sum up to `c`.

**Performance**: the trade-off between performance and code length is made such that most test cases finish within some seconds. The following variant would save 14 bytes, but would be much less performant:

```scala
(n,x,i)=>0 to 1<<30 find(c=>Seq.fill(x)(1 to c).flatten.combinations(x).count(_.map(Math.pow(_, i)).sum==c)==n)
```